# Sed Error "extra characters at the end of g command"

Tags: linux, unix, sed

This is my Sed command:

```
sed -i 's:io.gatling.app.Gatling:io.gatling.app.Gatling -s "redirects.RedirectLoad" -df /opt/gatling/user-files/data:g' gatling.sh
```

gatling.sh contains the following:

```
"$JAVA" $DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$GATLING_CLASSPATH" io.gatling.app.Gatling "$@"
```

I'm getting a few issues, mostly due to the whitespaces and `/` characters. I thought I'd fixed it but now i'm getting extra character errors.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The only thing I'd comment on is that the expression should be single quoted.

Comment: Try using single quotes around the sed command, see http://rextester.com/DBC81663

Comment: Still getting the same issue with single quotes, updated my post to reflect that i'm now using single quotes.


command:  sed -i 's:io.gatling.app.Gatling:io.gatling.app.Gatling -s "redirects.RedirectLoad" -df /opt/gatling/user-files/data:g' gatling.sh

error:  sed: 1: "gatling.sh": extra characters at the end of g command

Comment: I assume this is related to the file directory after the command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Was missing the `-e`.

This did the job:

```
sed -i -e 's:io.gatling.app.Gatling:io.gatling.app.Gatling -s "redirects.RedirectLoad" -df /opt/gatling/user-files/data:g' gatling.sh
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem - for me my shell script containing the `sed` command even worked locally, but not on some CI system. Adding `-e` before the `s`-string made it work on all environments. No idea why, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same error, and was only missing the space between -e and the command.

Comment: to running multiple `sed` commands so you need to use `-e` .

Answer (score 0):

As if here the closing quotation mark would be missing (here I replaced it):

sed -i "s:io.gatling.app.Gatling:io.gatling.app.Gatling"

Comment: I'm assuming the `-s ...` text is part of the replacement text, not an argument to `sed`.

Comment: Yeah the target text I want to replace:  io.gatling.app.Gatling

To be replaced with: io.gatling.app.Gatling -s "redirects.RedirectLoad" -df /opt/gatling/user-files/data